# What is the most efficient arrangement of Iron Golem Spawners in a chunk to maximize drops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I came up across a very interesting problem on an online server that I play on.

They had a plugin called chunk collector, which instantly kills all mobs in a particular chunk that are spawned, and collects it's drops. There is no y limit of the chunk collector. Following are the conditions:

1. Chunk Collector: instantly kills all mobs in a chunk
2. Given infinite iron golem spawners
3. One chunk collector
4. One player who has to be afk/not moving

Question: What is orientation of spawners to get the best drop rate?

Comment: Don't know if this is the best place to ask this question.